# R: Merge data conditional on cells

Tags: r, merge

I have a data frame `df1` that has a main variable `main_v` and a variable that sometimes has an additional comment in it, `additional_v`:

```
df1:
    main_v additional_v
    city1
    city2 200 sq mi
    city3 100 inhabitants
    city2 10 mio inhabitants
    city4
    city1
    city4
    city1 10 sq mi
```

I want to do the following: merge the same `main_v` entries whenever `additional_v` is empty and keep one entry. When `additional_v` is not empty, keep each instance of `main_v`. The individual `additional_v` entries should not be combined for every `main_v` but kept as separate entries.

The resulting `df2` should look something like this:

```
df2:
    main_v   additional_v
        city1
        city1 10 sq mi
        city2 200 sq mi
        city2 10 mio inhabitants
        city3 100 inhabitants
        city4
```

I don't know how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated. I don't have a preference for particular `packages`.

Comment: Would `unique(df1)` works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df1) %>%
    arrange(main_v)
```

---

Or with `unique` from `base R`

```
unique(df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(main_v = c("city1", "city2", "city3", "city2", 
"city4", "city1", "city4", "city1"), additional_v = c("", "200 sq mi", 
"100 inhabitants", "10 mio inhabitants", "", "", "", "10 sq mi"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thanks! What is row.names = c(NA, -8L))?

Comment: @questionmark It is the structure output when you do `dput` i.e. `dput(head(iris))`

Comment: That's very helpful, I appreciate your help!